# How do I ask questions for the live podcast?

Tags: support, podcast

There is a live podcast but I'm not sure how to ask questions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You enter [the chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/512/se-podcast), and post them there. If enough folks star them, and the hosts consider them interesting / on-topic, they'll be answered.

Note that this only applies *while a podcast is currently being recorded*. Questions posted *after* the podcast will likely be ignored.

Comment: The existence of the chat room should have been made clear on the [Livestream webpage](http://www.livestream.com/stackexchange?cb=1) (e.g. in the "About This Channel" box), cause I was looking for this as well.

Comment: AFAIK, it was supposed to be (and has been in the past) - not sure why it wasn't there today, other than we haven't used this in a while.